# laravel accessors in controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5, accessor, mutators

I've add accessors and mutators in my laravel model.

```
public function getAmountAttribute($amount)
{
    return ($amount) / 100;
}
public function setAmountAttribute($amount)
{
    $this->attributes['amount'] = $amount * 100;
}
```

These are working fine for me. At one place i am facing issue :
The issue is I want to apply aggregate function in my controller for amount field. But accessors is not working.

```
Model::with(['xxx'])->where('parent_id', $id)->sum('amount')
```

Value of $id is fine i checked. It's giving me sum of amount field where parent_id is equals to $id. It should give results after diving by 100.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attributes when
>   retrieving them from a model or setting their value.

... not while querying the table.

```
Model::with(['xxx'])
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(`table`.amount/100) as sum_of_amounts'))
    ->where('parent_id', $id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

An accessor/mutator is called only when you access the property from the result but it doesn't work within the query so you can't do it but as an alternative, you may use Laravel's [Collection::sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sum) method for example:

```
$collection = Model::with(['xxx'])->where('parent_id', $id)->get();
$someOfAmount = $collection->sum('amount');
```

Make sure that, you've created a protected `$appends` property in your `Model` in use where it has the following:

```
protected $appends = ['amount'];
```

---

*Note: I'm not sure whether this `$appends` is required but you may give this a try.*

Comment: As per my thinking $appends should be use when we don't have field in database and wanted to include with our collection.

[Use of accessor in eloquent](http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/)

But it's a good idea to use in this way as per your answer. Thanks